# Http File Transfer using Commons VFS

Tags: java, apache-commons-vfs

Can any one provide me an example implementation to transfer files from http server to Local using Commons VFS API.

I have tried below code,

```
StandardFileSystemManager manager = new StandardFileSystemManager();
    manager.init();
    if ("http".equals(source.getScheme())) {
            manager.addProvider("http", new HttpFileProvider());
            manager.setCacheStrategy(CacheStrategy.ON_CALL);
            manager.setFilesCache(new SoftRefFilesCache());
    } else if ("https".equals(source.getScheme())) {
            manager.addProvider("https", new HttpsFileProvider());
            manager.setCacheStrategy(CacheStrategy.ON_CALL);
            manager.setFilesCache(new SoftRefFilesCache());
    }...
```

But I am getting the error below while trying to run.

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Multiple providers registered for URL scheme "http".
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.addProvider(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:180)
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.addProvider(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:158)
at com.scb.smartbatch.adapters.VFSAdapter.copyFiles(VFSAdapter.java:150)
at com.scb.smartbatch.adapters.VFSAdapter.send(VFSAdapter.java:762)
... 33 more
```

Please provide inputs whether I missed something here.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `StandardFileSystemManager()` it will read its configuration from the classpath (from provider.xml and vfs-provider.xml files in the core and sandbox jar). It is therefore already initialized with providers for http and https.

You can either do `if (manager.hasProvider("http"))` around adding the provider or you just skip adding the providers and rely on automatic configuration. Typically you would use `VFS.getManager()` to get a fully configured FileSystemManager with all known providers registered.

If you want to configure the manager compeltely by hand, you would use a `new DefaultFileSystemManger()` instead. (this requires to add [stuff like cache, replicator and so on](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/api.html)).